# Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-split'

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to make a split view and I have problems importing [react-split](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-split).

When I import and add it to my code I don't see any problems.
Then, I see that in my editor on the line `import Split from "react-split"` there are three points and when I hover them it says:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-split'. '/home/user/Documents/test/node_modules/react-split/dist/react-split.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Try `npm install @types/react-split` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-split';`ts(7016)

If I try and run npm install @types/react-split I get

> npm ERR! code E404
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2freact-split - Not found
> npm ERR! 404
> npm ERR! 404  '@types/react-split@latest' is not in the npm registry.
> npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
> npm ERR! 404
> npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
> npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

When I create a .d.ts file and i declare the module I still don't get this problem resolved and the message stays there.

Any idea how to fix this? I tried everything that was suggested and saw some similar stack questions but nothing that fixes.

Edit: I am pretty new to web dev, it seems that it asks for typescript? I wonder why? I installed typescript but the package is still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@types/react-split-pane has been deprecated

you should use [react-split-pane](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-split-pane)

react-split-pane provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/react-split-pane installed

Answer (score 1):

It seems they have pending to release this file:
https://github.com/nathancahill/split/blob/8a51b9d79b44f8fa602cf2bf984c5408f43308b9/packages/react-split/index.d.ts

just download it to your node-modules/react-split folder, for me was enough

Comment: Think is probably the correct answer (for now) rather than accepted one. [react-split-pane](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-split-pane) not the same as [react-split](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-split). I used this [index.d.ts](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nathancahill/split/master/packages/react-split/index.d.ts)